# jQuery button click not submitting button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble getting the following code to work. I have a form that has several buttons on it. The first button has a class of `ButtonAdditionalDelete`. When it is clicked, it should then inspect the object for a data tag and then set the value of the tag to a hidden variable. Finally, it should then click the button with the id of `saveAnswerButton`.

However, when the form is submitted back to the server, the `action` variable from the button is not present. Any ideas?

```
<form action="/Area/Controller/Action/id?otherField=value" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SelectedSequenceNumber)
    <button class="ButtonAdditionalDelete" data-sequence-number="1">Delete</button>

    <button name="action" value="AnswerEdit" id="saveButton">Save</button>
    <button name="action" value="AnswerEditAndAdd">Save and Add New</button>
    <button name="action" value="AnswerEditAndReturn">Save and Return</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ButtonAdditionalDelete").on("click", function () {
    var sequenceNumber = $(this).data("sequenceNumber");
    $("#SelectedSequenceNumber").val(sequenceNumber);
    $("#saveButton").click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `#saveButton` element? All I can see is `#saveAnswerButton`.

Comment: Shouldn't `$("#saveButton").click()` be `$("#saveAnswerButton").click()`?

Comment: It seems there is some relevant code missing from your question - I can't see `#SelectedSequenceNumber` either.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with this - You're on the right track, but we need to see more of the code.

Comment: Sorry everyone, that was a mistake on my part. I updated the code to correct the issue with the id of the button!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
$("#saveButton").click();
```

supposed to be

```
$("#saveAnswerButton").click();
```

Comment: This was an error on my part. I updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

that's a security measure. the name and value of a button will only be sent if it's a human click.

you'll have to keep a hidden input called action, then change it's value just before simulating the form submit:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="hiddenAction" name="action" type="hidden" value="">
    <button class="ButtonAdditionalDelete" data-sequence-number="1">Delete</button>

    <button name="action" value="AnswerEdit" id="saveAnswerButton">Save</button>
    <button name="action" value="AnswerEditAndAdd">Save and Add New</button>
    <button name="action" value="AnswerEditAndReturn">Save and Return</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ButtonAdditionalDelete").on("click", function () {
    var sequenceNumber = $(this).data("sequenceNumber");
    $("#SelectedSequenceNumber").val(sequenceNumber);
    $("#hiddenAction").val($("#saveAnswerButton").val());
    $("#saveAnswerButton").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, you are using *sequenceNumber* but your attribute is called *sequence-number*.

Comment: The question is about the `action` variable.

Comment: jQuery automatically converts camel-cased strings into a dashed string and then prepending data- to the result. http://api.jquery.com/data/